# Need to create a java code that will sort numbers

Tags: java, sorting

Need a java code that will sort integers in order.

This is a portion of my code but when I try to compile it, it says that it is missing a return statement. I am confused about how to fix this.

```
 public double getSmallest()
   {

      if (num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3)

          return num1;


      if (num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num1)

          return num2;


      if (num3 <= num1 && num3 <= num2)

          return num3;


    }
```

Comment: what happens if none of the conditions are true? Therein lies the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return a value in the case that none of these conditions are true.

Either return a meaningless value like `Double.MIN_VALUE` (at least, meaningless in 99.9% of the cases) or throw an exception (a lot better!): `throw new IllegalArgumentException()`.

Or, probably better: just refactor your conditions to make them automatically default to one value since that is really how this method should work. Like a waterfall.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the compiler only sees `return` statements within `if` statements.  It thinks there's no guaranteed path through the method that has a `return`.

Something like this would work:

```
if(num1 <= num2 && num1 <= num3) { 
  return num1;
} else if(num2 <= num1 && num2 <= num1) {
  return num2;
} else { //by matter of deduction
  return num3;
}
```

---

Another possible solution:

```
public double getSmallest() {
    double min = num1;
    if(min > num2) {
        min = num2;
    }
    if(min > num3) {
        min = num3;
    }
    return min;
}
```

As a note, this particular solution is easily the most scalable.  If instead of a handful of numbers, you had an `array` of numbers, you could assign `min` to the value of the first index, and then iterate through the entire collection comparing the value at each index to `min`, and if it's smaller, reassign `min`.

---

Above are probably the two best and most logical solutions.  However, simply adding `return 0` (or ANY `return` statement) after all the `if` statements will make the compiler happy.  This will work... but it's sloppy in my opinion (at least in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using an `else if` chain but three separated `if`s according to the compiler what can happen is that if `c1` and `c2` and `c3` are all `false`

```
if (c1)
  return ..; << not executed
if (c2)
  return ..; << not executed
if (c3)
  return ..; << not executed
<< code flow arrives here but method ends: no return value
```

First of all, since these are mutually exclusive situations, you could use an `else if`:

```
if (c1)
  return ..;
else if (c2)
  return ..;
else if (c3)
  return ..;
else
  return 0; // will never be called
```

But since last case will never be chosen, because at least one condition will be true you can simply go:

```
if (c1)
  return ..;
else if (c2)
  return ..;
else
  return ..;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding message *it is missing a return statement*, it is because in the following situation:

**what it none of the 3 if condition is satisfied.**

Have a try with the following code:

```
    public double getSmallest() {

       return num1 < num2 ? (num1 < num3 ? num1 : num3) : (num2 < num3 ? num2
            : num3);
    }
```

or

```
    public double getSmallest() {

       if (num1 < num2) {
           return num1 < num3 ? num1 : num3;
       } else {
           return num2 < num3 ? num2 : num3;
       }
    }
```